# One word for "Besides knowing my advantages, I also know my drawbacks"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I wish to point out some drawbacks on my own research work after I have praised it.

> As a _____, I am aware of my work's drawbacks, which could be fixed if
>   I had more time.

Is there an adjective or noun for this?

Comment: That introductory bit is unnecessary, and indeed braggy. Whatever word you put in the blank, it comes off as if you're patting yourself on the back. For a very trivial thing to boot. So go ahead and lose it. You are aware that your work's not perfect, so say just that and be done.

Comment: What RegDwigHt said, plus, do you really mean drawbacks?  "drawback: a hindrance or disadvantage; an undesirable or objectionable feature" (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drawback).  Do you mean limitations?  As for "fixed if I had more time", this is unnecessarily honest.  The usual phrase is "expanded if I got a juicy research grant", more tactfully expressed, of course.

Comment: Continuing with the "nicer word than drawbacks" topic, you could talk about the **scope** of your work.  This immediately implies that any issues with it were just due to limited resources rather than any failing on your part.  For example, to reword the whole sentence:  "I'm aware of the limitations in the scope of this work, and I hope to address those in further studies".

Comment: Are you Donald Trump?

Comment: @Max Williams Your wording is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for literally "***self-aware***", as in

> *Bob is **self-aware***

or

> *Bob is a **self-aware** person*

Or, if you want to get really fancy and obscure, try "***autognositic***" on for size. From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autognosis):

> ***autognosis***: *(noun)  Self-knowledge; the understanding of one's character and peculiarities.*

Comment: +1 for the fanciness of autognositic. (Apple dictionary doesn't have it) I will go with self-aware, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ['Realist'](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=realist&button=Search)

> a person who accepts the world as it literally is and deals with it accordingly;

or maybe ['Pragmatist'](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=pragmatist&button=Search)

> a person who takes a practical approach to problems and is concerned primarily with the success or failure of her actions;

Answer (score 1):

Using **opportunity areas** sounds more positive.

> As a _____, I am aware of my work's opportunity areas, which could be improved/fixed if I had more time.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives would be **objective** or **impartial**:

> Being *objective*, I am aware of my work's drawbacks, which could be fixed if I had more time.

Objective ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/objective))

> 5. not influenced by personal feelings, interpretations, or prejudice; based on facts; unbiased

Impartial ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impartial))

> 1. not partial or biased; fair; just

Answer (score 0):

"principal" might be a different tack, acknowledging some partiality on the research, but also expertise and familiarity with its shortcomings.

Comment: "As a principal"?

Comment: @NVZ *Principal* could refer to the 'main' person behind an effort. I think Dex Stakker is suggesting that since the OP did the work, the OP can be expected to know its weak points. The indefinite article is awkward for a single-person effort, though.

Comment: *Tact* means something like *manners* or *politeness*. You might want to choose a different word. Also, it would improve your answer if you explain your reasoning.

Comment: I meant to use the word 'tack' (a method of dealing with a situation or problem) which I have corrected my answer to use. to. I learned that word phonetically as tact (because it seemed to make sense as a different tactic), so I often mix them up when I am typing and not saying it aloud.

Comment: @Lawrence: yes, regarding principal, it sounded like the asker was one of the principal authors of the paper that they were presenting and therefore could conceivably cite that as implying the expertise and will to reflect on the papers weaknesses. It wasn't an answer that was congruent with the request, but it was a different way of presenting the what they were eventually trying to say. And even now I am talking as if there were multiple people involved when the asker only mentioned themself. So, "the principal" is what I should have said.