# Adjective for someone who knows their limits

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives, epithet-requests

I am looking for adjectives for describing a person who knows their limits, what they are capable of and what not, knows their weak and strong points.

Usage example: When you are going through a new adventure (or having a difficult time in order to change something) in your life, try to find your limits and strengths along the way. Once you are done with it, you become a more [word] person.

I know this sounds like a simple question, but I, as a non-English speaking person, just can't think of good adjectives for it. I could think of wise, clear-minded, etc. but I am not happy with what I came up with.

Comment: "realistic" maybe?

Comment: "Pragmatic person"? - One who is practical.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan Sounds really good, thanks!

Comment: _Balanced_ may also work; context affects the choice. The usual way to express this is the way you explain the question, 'a person who is well aware of their strengths and weaknesses'. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Pragmatic is a pretty good choice: although the definition doesn't as-such specify knowing personal limits or strong/weak points, it is "solving problems in a sensible way that suits the current conditions" which would logically include a consideration of one's own ability.

Comment: The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Rathony added a usage example to show how the word would be used.

Comment: I think the question is clear. I have voted to reopen. In the interim, can I suggest either *[self-aware, or the obscure latinate term autognostic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204954/one-word-for-besides-knowing-my-advantages-i-also-know-my-drawbacks/204959#204959)*?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I think the crux of the matter is this: What is the word for it in your mother tongue? If there isn't one, please specify your reasons for thinking there must be one in English. If there is one, then please look up its translation into English in a dictionary of your choosing. (The purpose of this site is not to be a bilingual dictionary, we ask that of everyone.) And if there is one, but you can't think of it, then the question is not about English.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The best word I can think of in my mother language is translated to "wise" and "pragmatic." But I don't read much in my mother language :)))
I don't know, perhaps English does not have a word either. I really like the word "pragmatic" in this context.

Comment: @DanBron I have already edited the question, but still some people still want to close it. If we can be a bit nicer to each other, the world would be a better place.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I do think *wise* works just fine in English, too. "Once you are done with it, you become a more wise person." I am not seeing any issues with that. *Pragmatic* could or could not work depending on context, as it is a more, um, dry, technical-sounding word than *wise*.

Comment: This type of person who displays **self awareness**  and is therefore **self aware**. Self awareness as explained in this [article](http://www.pathwaytohappiness.com/self-awareness.htm) is what you are looking for. (Someone who knows their strengths and weaknesses)

Comment: When you are going through a new adventure (or having a difficult time in order to change something) in your life, try to find your limits and strengths along the way. Once you are done with it, you become a more **mature** person

Comment: Secure is the word.

Comment: Reflective, self-considered, self-known, wise, aware, practiced, mature.

Comment: I'd agree with @Jon that self-aware is most appropriate given the usage example. Self-aware means knowing more about yourself (including limits, strengths, and weaknesses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, the answer would be self-aware, pragmatic, or wise.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Quote definitions, and if possible, link to a dictionary. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a saying for this in Chinese, it is "自知之明". I tried to find an English translation or equivalent and the closest thing I found was "self knowledge". You can refer to the definition [here](https://www.linguee.com/chinese-english/translation/%E8%87%AA%E7%9F%A5%E4%B9%8B%E6%98%8E.html).